How to use php artisan in gitlab-ci?
I have the following .gitlab-ci.yml file:
stages:
  - pull
  - optimize

variables:
  GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY: "1"

before_script:
  - git config --global http.sslVerify false
  - git config --global credential.helper store
  - echo "https://${CI_REPOSITORY_USER}:${CI_REPOSITORY_PASSWORD}@gitlab.com" > ~/.git-credentials

pull_job:
  stage: pull
  script:
    - echo "Pulling the project on the server through git"
    - git pull origin master
  only:
    - master

It works well. Now I need to execute one more command after pulling to clear the cache:
php artisan optimize

So, I add this at the end of file above:
optimize_job:
  stage: optimize
  script:
    - echo "Clearing the cache by optimize command.."
    - php artisan optimize

It throws:

.gitlab-ci.yml returns /usr/bin/bash: line 156: php: command not found error

Any idea how can I fix it?

Is PHP installed in the container image that gitlab is using?

I don't use Docker @AlexHowansky

OK so if gitlab is running the pipe directly on the host, then it seems PHP is not in the environment's PATH. What is the full path to the php executable?

When I go to the project root by cd /var/www/html/api and then run php artisan optimize manually, it works well. @AlexHowansky

btw @AlexHowansky, /usr/bin/php -v returns PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.18 (cli) ... as well

Update the config so it runs ls -l /usr/bin/php, echo $PATH and /usr/bin/php artisan optimize and then capture the output.

You mean replacing these three commands with php artisan optimize in the config file?

In place of php artisan optimize, add those three commands.

@AlexHowansky https://i.sstatic.net/VIwBLfth.png

There you go, new error. I'm guessing that you probably need a composer install step in there before you run the optimize.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Oh, you are right, it’s one step forward. Just do you know wouldn’t it use the existed “vendor” directory which is on the root? @AlexHowansky

It shouldn't, this is the whole point of pipelines, to run these tests in a fresh clean new isolated environment. (Which is why they're usually done in containers.)

Oh I see, got it @AlexHowansky. You helped me too much

just I don't understand, so why when I run git pull command in the gitlab ci, it gets applied on the real directories, but when I run composer install command it has no effect on the vendor?

"it gets applied on the real directories" What makes you think this?

@AlexHowansky, Really? I'm wrong? I though the ci has been invented to make the whole process automatic (process of pulling a new version of the code on the production server after merging to master branch)

"process of pulling a new version of the code on the production server after merging to master branch" You're describing a deployment, which is only one of dozens of things that a CI/CD pipeline might do. In general, each pipeline instance is going to spin up a temporary new empty environment, install fresh code to it, run its tasks there, and then purge the install. It should never touch your local development environment and it should never touch the remote/origin repo.
